# Content overflowing out of the card Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

All my content inside  is overflowing out of the card.

```
<md-content ng-controller="TestCtrl" layout-padding>
<div layout="row" style="height: calc(100vh - 64px);">
<!-- left sidenav : search and search results -->
<div layout="column" flex-gt-sm="30" style="background-color: #fafafa;">
   <md-content layout="column" flex class="search-results" layout-margin style="overflow: auto;">
    <span class="md-subhead muted">Results: </span>
    <md-card ng-repeat="place in places" class="result-card" layout="column">
        <md-card-content flex>
            <h2 class="title">{{place.first_name}} {{place.last_name}}</h2>
            <h4 class="sub-cat">Prospect Status: <span class="state">{{place.prospect_status}}</span></h4>
            <h4 class="sub-cat">Spiritual Condition: <span class="state">{{place.spiritual_condition}}</span></h4>
            <h4 class="sub-cat">Street: <span class="state">{{place.address[0].street_no}}</span></h4>
            <h4 class="sub-cat">Prospect Status: <span class="state">{{place.prospect_status}}</span></h4>
            <h4 class="sub-cat">Spiritual Condition: <span class="state">{{place.spiritual_condition}}</span></h4>
            <h4 class="sub-cat">Street: <span class="state">{{place.address[0].street_no}}</span></h4>
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
</md-content>
</div>
</div>
```

here's a [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/wVSOUAgZv4v5XgJNZzOo?p=preview) to the plunker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the `layout="column"` from your md-content component:

```
<md-content flex class="search-results" layout-margin style="overflow: auto;">
```

Comment: I had a smiliar issue and removing the  `layout="row"` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the `layout-fill` attribute to your `md-card`:

```html
<md-card ng-repeat="place in places" class="result-card" layout="column" layout-fill>...</md-card>
```

[Updated Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MMe6zgSN1C9DjqtQY9jF?p=preview)